# store object into php variable

Tags: php

I'm newbie so apologize for my stupid question
In my Function i have to return the object and store the object into another variable..
If it's possible than how can i do it?
 My_function is:

```
     function check_id($newOrders,$orderId){
     $length=count($newOrders);
     echo $length;
     for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){   
     if($newOrders[$i]->$orderId == $orderId)
     return $newOrders[$i]; //return Object
     }
   return null;
        }
```

My function call is:

```
check_id($newOrders,$orderId);
```

can i store the above return value into the $temp(variable) and after that use it for eg:

```
 $temp=check_id($newOrders,$orderId);
```

Comment: Have you checked it if it works? And why two times $temp=$temp=

Comment: @AD7six my question is in check_id function when function return the $newOrders[$i] / Null, can i store the return value into the $temp(variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why on earth not?

**[RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)**

```
$obj   = (object) array('1' => 'foo');
$obj2  = new stdClass(); 
$obj3  = aFunctionWhichReturnsAnObject();

// Do whatever with those objects. Doesnt matter whether a function returned them.
```

> AD7six my question is in check_id function when function return the $newOrders[$i] / Null, can i store the return value into the $temp(variable)

Yes, of course

```
$temp=check_id($newOrders,$orderId);
var_dump($temp);
```

Comment: i have one more doubt,i want to insert an object into the an array....
**$order=new Order($row['id'], $row['tableId'], $row['createdDate']);**
**$newOrder[]=$order;**
but when i check through **var_dump($newOrders);**
it show null value

Comment: Ok so is there no difference between `$newOrder` and `$newOrders` ? :)

Comment: Sorry typing mistake 
**$newOrders[]=$order;**